# SQL: using case when to change column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating new columns but in particular I want to say if a value of a column is equal to a value, then change a corresponding column. For example:

```
SELECT
     Col1 as c1
    ,Col2 as c2
    ,CASE CAST([COB] as varchar(50))
        WHEN 'Engineering' then set c1 = 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [Class of Business]
FROM
     ....
```

but I can't get it to work, for instance if a entry in the column [COB] was 'engineering' then I want it to set (on the same row) the column c1 to 0, else just fill the column c1 with 0's

Comment: do you have to `update` the table?

Comment: No,I am just querying it

Comment: Please post a data set and a wished result set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to query your table, you can return 1 or 0 in base of COB status without reassign to `c1` the new value.

Try this:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN CAST([COB] as varchar(50)) = 'Engineering' then 1
    ELSE Col1
END AS c1,
Col2 as c2
FROM ...
```

Comment: The problem is I want to set the column c1 as 0 or 1, not the [Class of Business] column

Comment: @user33484: Ok, have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way `SELECT` works.  You're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    --Col1 as c1
    CASE CAST([COB] as varchar(50))
        WHEN 'Engineering' then 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS c1 
    ,Col2 as c2
    ,COB as [Class of Business]
FROM
```

Comment: The problem is I want to set the column c1 as 0 or 1, not the [Class of Business] column

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

So when COB = Engineering you want c1 to be 1 otherwise just the current value of C1.
If that is the cae then......

```
SELECT
    CASE CAST([COB] as varchar(50))
        WHEN 'Engineering' then 1
        ELSE c1
    END AS c1
    ,Col2 as c2
FROM
..
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing the `cast()`?

```
SELECT Col1 as c1,
       Col2 as c2,
       (CASE WHEN [COB] = 'Engineering' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Class of Business]
FROM . . .;
```

You *can* use a searched `CASE` for this purpose.  But with one comparison, I think the above is easier to read.

Comment: CAST because this is part of a bigger query where I needed to use CAST. Your code here will change the class of business column to 0 or 1, but I don't want to change that at all I only want to change Col1